# To find how many characters are remaining from a total of 140, slice function

Tags: javascript, jscript

To do that I have written code below

```
var tweet = prompt("compose your tweet");
var tweetcount = tweet.length;
alert("you have written " + tweetcount + " characters you have " + (140 - tweetcount) + " characters remaining. ");
var tweet = "cut down your tweet";
tweetcount.slice(141, 1);
```

While it effectively gives a prompt to write and after that tells how many characters left + over limit of characters.
But in the console why does it say `tweetcount.slice` is not a function?

Comment: `var tweetcount = tweet.length;` therefore `tweetcount` is a number. `.slice()` is available on strings and arrays.

Comment: BTW tweets support 280 characters now

Comment: I need it to automatically cut down to 140 characters. How would i do that?

Comment: The arguments to `slice` are the start and end index. Are you trying to do: `tweet.slice(0,140)`?

Comment: Yes i was trying to do tweet.slice(0,140) but it only shows how many characters have exceeded. How would make it automatically erase excess words? p.s im new so don't know how to properly format in stack overflow.

Comment: `tweet = tweet.slice(0,140)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var tweet = prompt ("compose your tweet"); var tweetunder140 = tweet.slice(0,140); alert(tweetunder140);`